# PHP file_put_contents new line issue

Tags: php

I'm unable to write array to text file in new lines. My code:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($final_result);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output**:

```
Array

(
    [0] => Something1
    [1] => Something2
    [2] => Something3
)
```

**Then**:

```
file_put_contents($file, trim($final_result . "\n"), FILE_APPEND);
```

**Output**:

```
Something1Something2Something3Array
```

**My goal is**:

```
Something1
Something2
Something3
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: (
    [0] => Something1\n
    [1] => Something2\n
    [2] => Something3\n
)

Comment: Most likely the file is written on a platform that uses a different line separator than you're using to open it. A simple regexp like `preg_replace("#([\n\r]{1,2})#", "\r\n", $final_result);` would probably solve it.

Comment: You trim the new line you put after $final_result

Comment: Sorted by Phil, thanks guys :)

Comment: TIL: `file_put_contents` accepts an array :)

Answer (score 17):

How about

```
file_put_contents($file, implode(PHP_EOL, $final_result), FILE_APPEND);
```

Comment: The idea with `implode(PHP_EOL, ...)` is very useful, thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

Different platforms use different new-line characters. To over come this, php provides built in constant that takes care of them all: PHP_EOL

Answer (score 1):

Your array should be in this way to insert a new line after each value

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Something1\n
    [1] => Something2\n
    [2] => Something3\n
  )
```

Doing this:

```
file_put_contents($file, trim($final_result . "\n"), FILE_APPEND);
```

You are inserting a new line after the complete array

As @NielsKeurentjes said you have to see in which plataform you are writing the file:

\r = CR (Carriage Return) // Used as a new line character in Unix

\n = LF (Line Feed) // Used as a new line character in Mac OS

\r\n = CR + LF // Used as a new line character in Windows